# Sphinx - Multiple fulltext search reduces exact match score

Tags: php, sphinx

I encountered a strange `weight` issue with Sphinx. When performed fulltext only on `name`, the results are weighted accurately. But when it's extended with search on `address`, the weight calculated is incorrect.

I'm using `Sphinx 2.2.11`

**Example 1:** Search on name yields proper results

```
$cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@weight desc');
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$res = $cl->Query('@name ("la" | "comedie" | "saint" | "michel")', 'idx_name');
```

> Output

```
      Venue Name                               Address          Weight
La Comédie Saint-Michel                 boulevard Saint-Michel  19620
La Comédie Saint-Michel - Small Hall    boulevard Saint-Michel  18649
La Comédie Saint-Michel - Grande Salle  boulevard Saint-Michel  18649
```

> Words to match

```
[words] => Array
    (
        [la] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 26110
                [hits] => 29358
            )

        [comedie] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 89
                [hits] => 96
            )

        [saint] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 8820
                [hits] => 10171
            )

        [michel] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 314
                [hits] => 353
            )
    )
```

**Example 2:** Search on name and address gets incorrect weight

```
$cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@weight desc');
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$res = $cl->Query('@name ("la" | "comedie" | "saint" | "michel")
                   @address ("boulevard" | "saint" | "michel")', 'idx_name');
```

> Output

```
      Venue Name                               Address          Weight    
La Comédie Saint-Michel - Small Hall    boulevard Saint-Michel  32631
La Comédie Saint-Michel - Grande Salle  boulevard Saint-Michel  32631
La Comédie Saint-Michel                 boulevard Saint-Michel  32608
```

> Words to match

```
[words] => Array
    (
        [la] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 26110
                [hits] => 29358
            )

        [comedie] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 89
                [hits] => 96
            )

        [saint] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 8820
                [hits] => 10171
            )

        [michel] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 314
                [hits] => 353
            )

        [boulevard] => Array
            (
                [docs] => 19735
                [hits] => 19915
            )
    )
```

In example 2, third record should have got highest weightage.
Output expected is best/exact match to be on top. I tried using different ranking modes, but no luck.

Comment: This is going to sound crazy, but can you check if  `SPH_RANK_SPH04` is actually defined? There is a bug on old and not so old sphinx PHP libraries where this constant is missing, and therefore sph04 would not be used.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, yes `SPH_RANK_SPH04` is defined in `PHP Sphinx` library

Comment: Okay, so it's not that bug. Just wanted to make sure before I dig deeper :-)

Comment: I'm ready to try all possibilities. Sometimes minor change fixes huge problem. Appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: I'm using OR because if out of 4 only 3 words match, I still want them in the result but weighted appropriately. For e.g. If venue name is `la comedie st michel` ( note the word 'st'), it should return those 3 results.

Comment: @Samir Can you show what you get in $res['words']?

Comment: Never mind. This looks like a bug to me. I've opened an issue about this in Manticore's bug tracker https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/issues/144 Thanks for pointing this out. If it's indeed a bug we'll fix it.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch, have added words in my post for each example. Thank you for considering this issue. Please post it here if you find any fix or alternative. Thanks once again!